# How to change column name including dot in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have made a data.frame after using aggregate, then I tried to change the column names of some columns. The data.frame (df) as:

```
  DistanceFromBase Layer Nitrogen    x.mean      x.sd
1                5   1-2       HN 50.884615 10.841870
2               10   1-2       HN 64.846154  8.008457
3               15   1-2       HN 65.538462  7.500564
4               20   1-2       HN 65.461538  8.448577
5               25   1-2       HN 65.000000  9.055385
6               30   1-2       HN 65.565217  9.806427
```

I used

```
colnames(df)
```

and the colnames as:

```
[1] "DistanceFromBase" "Layer"            "Nitrogen"         "x"
```

I want to change the column names "x.mean" and "x.sd" to "mean" and "sd", respectively.

```
colnames(df)[4] <- "mean"
```

can only change the "x" to "mean", as:

```
  DistanceFromBase Layer Nitrogen mean.mean   mean.sd
1                5   1-2       HN 50.884615 10.841870
2               10   1-2       HN 64.846154  8.008457
3               15   1-2       HN 65.538462  7.500564
4               20   1-2       HN 65.461538  8.448577
5               25   1-2       HN 65.000000  9.055385
6               30   1-2       HN 65.565217  9.806427
```

How to change column names "x.mean" and "x.sd" to "mean" and "sd".

Comment: I strongly suspect that what looks like your last two columns is actually a single list with two elements. Can you show us how you generated your data frame? Also, run `dim(df)` to see whether you have four or five columns.

Comment: @nograpes, I would predict not a `list`, but an `array`. I would suggest to the OP using `df <- do.call(data.frame, df)` first.

Comment: @nograpes I use the code:   'aggregate(df, df[c("DistanceFromBase", "Layer","Nitrogen" )],FUN=function(x) c(mean =mean(x), sd=sd(x) )  )'.    I have run 'dim(df)', it has four columns.

Comment: @zongshiwujie, yes, but your fourth column itself is a `matrix`. Try the code I suggested for a solution.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto, After I used    'df <- do.call(data.frame, df)'    , I can change the column names now, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `aggregate` like that with multiple functions, you'll end up with a `matrix` as a column:

```
output <- aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris[c(1, 5)], 
                    function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), Sum = sum(x)))
str(output)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 2 3
#  $ Sepal.Length: num [1:3, 1:2] 5.01 5.94 6.59 250.3 296.8 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   .. ..$ : NULL
#   .. ..$ : chr  "Mean" "Sum"
```

The easy way out of this is to use `do.call(data.frame, ...)` on the output, as in the following example.

```
output2 <- do.call(data.frame, output)
str(output2)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Species          : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 2 3
#  $ Sepal.Length.Mean: num  5.01 5.94 6.59
#  $ Sepal.Length.Sum : num  250 297 329
```

From there, you can rename your columns as usual.

Comment: +1 With perhaps a cheeky regex to do the renaming... `names(df) <- gsub( "x\\." , "" , names(df) )`?

Comment: @SimonO101, I need to use `do.call(data.frame, ...)` first, then I can used `names(df) <- gsub( "x\\." , "" , names(df) )` to replace the 'x'.